# R markdown: knitr and read_chunk not working

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)

I have an Rmd file, and I'm trying to run the following code within a chunk to source another .R file that is stored within the same project:

```
library(knitr)
```

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
# Read in all functions
read_chunk('functions/Functions.R')
```
````

When I run this chunk in isolation I don't get any error or warning messages, yet non of the the functions stored in 'Functions.R' are loaded.

Does anyone have any idea of why this might be?

Here is the directory structure I am using:

```
read_chunk('functions/Functions.R')
```

And here is an example of some of the code that is in 'Functions.R':

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

round_up = function(x, n) {
  posneg = sign(x)
  z = abs(x)*10^n
  z = z + 0.5
  z = trunc(z)
  z = z/10^n
  z*posneg
}
```

Note that Fucntions.R runs fine if I open that script and run `source()` on it. I don't get any errors or warning messages so I am confident that there aren't any issues with the code in Functions.R

Comment: Can you clarify the directory structure you are using and add an example of what might be in `Functions.R`?  That may help someone help you troubleshoot.  To show your code chunks in your question, use four back-ticks before pasting in the three back-ticks of the chunks.

Comment: @aosmith edits suggested have been made

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load functions stored in a script for use, I think you want `source()` instead of `knitr::read_chunk()`.

In that case you would use `source()` and use your functions in this or other chunks.

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
# Read in all functions
# knitr::read_chunk('functions/Functions.R')
source('functions/Functions.R')
```

```{r}
round_up(1, 2)
```
````

If you want to use `read_chunk()` instead you need to 1., name the chunks in your script and 2., make chunks in your RMD with the same names.

Here's code naming the first function in the `Functions.R` script as the chunk `my-label`.

```
## ---- my-label ----
round_up = function(x, n) {
     posneg = sign(x)
     z = abs(x)*10^n
     z = z + 0.5
     z = trunc(z)
     z = z/10^n
     z*posneg
}
```

Now you can use `read_chunk()` to read the chunks.  An empty chunk with the same chunk name actually runs the code from that chunk.  Once that's done the function is available within the RMD.

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
# Read in all functions
knitr::read_chunk('functions/Functions.R')
# source('functions/Functions.R')
```

```{r my-label, echo = FALSE}
```

```{r}
round_up(1, 2)
```
````

My impression is that one goal of `read_chunk()` is to allow you to insert results into the RMD without having to have all the code in your current document or run all the code in your script.  However, this relies on chunks and chunk names.  The `source()` function is to read an entire script, which seems more along the lines of what you are trying to do in this specific case.